# Java parsing String to Date returns wrong Date

Tags: java

I got the common problem that I want to parse a String to a Date.

The String looks like this `15.06.11 13:38:33 UTC`. But the result is `15.38.0011 13:38:33 UTC` when formatted with the same formatter used to parse the String to Date. TimeInMillis returns a negative value `-61818978087000`.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
formatter.setLenient(false);  
Date time = formatter.parse("15.06.11 13:38:33 UTC");    
Calendar timestamp = Calendar.getInstance();  
timestamp.setTime(time);
```

I m thankful for every help that I can get. Maybe I am making some stupid mistake but I dont see it. Please open my eyes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Months are `MM`, not `mm` (which is minutes)
and `yyyy` to `yy` (your year is 2-digit as it seems) (thanks to Peter for noticing that)

Answer (score 3):

Make it

```
dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss z
```

---

From [Doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
M   Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07
m   Minute in hour  Number  30
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the month to `MM` but also change the year to `yy` otherwise using `yyyy` it will assume that `15.06.11` was in the year `11` instead of `2011`

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss z")
                       .parse("15.06.11 13:38:33 UTC"));
```

prints for me (since I am GMT+1)

```
Wed Jun 15 14:38:33 BST 2011
```

Comment: I always try the code myself. I have been caught out many times assuming the rest of the code is right. ;)